# MIPS - inputs in two arrays

Tags: mips

I need to build a MIPS program that gets 20 integers from the user (every number have to be bigger than before, for example the inputs 3,5,4, or 3,4,4 are not correct) and put them in two arrays (each one gets 10 elements). The program should print the values in descendingly in base 10 and base 4 only if the values are in the both arrays (for example if we have the numbers -5,-6,2 in both arrays, it should print 2,-5,-6 and 2,-11,-12).

I have tried and wrote this code:

```
.data 
array1: .space 40 # first array store 10 integer elements 
arrend1:
array2: .space 40 # second array store 10 integer elements 

openMsg: .asciiz "Please enter 20 numbers: "

.text


main:
    # print openning message
    li      $v0,4 
    la      $a0, openMsg
    syscall 

    la      $t3, array1               # load base addr. of array1
    la      $t4, array2               # load base addr. of array2
    la      $t5, arrend1              # load address of array1 end

get_array: 

    # get the user's integar
    li      $v0, 5
    syscall 

    move    $t0, $v0                  # store the result in $t2
    sw      $t0, array1               # store word in register $t0 into RAM at address contained in $a1
    addi    $t3,$t3,4                 # increment array pointer

    blt     $t3,$t5,get_array         # branch to get_array if  i < 10
```

this code can only get inputs from the user and put it in the first array. how should I continue this?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use a compiler and C for example? Maybe you can write the working code in C, compile it and compare your code with the compiler code. MIPS is a RISC architecture so asm made by the compiler should be quite readable.

Comment: @DaanPape Is there a way to convert java into MIPS? because I don't know C, only java